# How to draw segments on image which is clickable and get the particular segment id in java

Tags: segment

I want to draw the segments on image according to the segment co-ordinates but the segments is becoming disalign on different phone screen and i want to get the particular id when i'll click on a particular segment

Here is the image which segments is properly designed
[image: Here is the image which segments is properly designed]

but the another one screen segments is becoming disalign
[image]